# TextView setText() called in callbacks from wrong context

Tags: java, android, callback, textview

I tried implementing a network service discovery and setting the name into a textView after successful registration. But I am getting an `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` exception. My basic structure looks like this:

```java
NsdManager.RegistrationListener mRegistrationListener;

onCreate() {
    mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
        onServiceRegistered(serviceInfo) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nsdServiceNameText);
            textView.setText(serviceInfo.getServiceName());
        }
    }
    
    mNsdManager = (NsdManager) this.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);

    mNsdManager.registerService(
        serviceInfo,
        NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD,
        mRegistrationListener);
}
```

It makes sense to me that I may be in the wrong context to edit the view but how did I get there and more importantly how do I solve this?

Comment: something moved you off the main thread. what that was, i don't know. how to fix it, link provided :)

Comment: Call setText() on UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation of `NsdManager` here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager

It says that:

> The API is asynchronous, and responses to requests from an application
> are on listener callbacks on a separate internal thread.

So it moves away from the UI thread which is where you should be updating your UI as pointed out in the comments as following:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(serviceInfo.getServiceName());
                }
            });
```